# Receiving empty response from jquery Ajax from a php file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am making a commenting reply system in PHP jquery and Ajax. So far I managed to make the commenting and reply to comment action with php and jquery ajax. When I reply to a comment, i receive back from the jquery ajax the number of replies to a comment and i print the number on the screen. Now what i want to do next is printing the reply to the screen after it was submitted. I made the jquery ajax function and wrote my php script. Then I echo the $output formated from the php back to the ajax. The problem is i am receiving blank response nevertheless i tested the php file directly and it is working perfectly and outputting to the screen the $output variable. Please help. Here is my ajax part that takes care of the output replies :

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    load_replies();
    function load_replies() {
     $.ajax({
     url: "widgets/board_reply_fetch.php?comment_id=<?php echo 
$board_comment_id_number;?>",
            method: "POST",
            success: function(data){
                $("#reply_comment").html(data);
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

and here is my php file :

```
<?php 
require_once '../includes/session.php';
require_once '../includes/functions.php';
require_once '../includes/validation_functions.php';

if (isset($_GET["comment_id"])) { 
$comment_id = (int)$_GET["comment_id"];

$reply_data = find_board_replies_by_comment_id($comment_id);

$output = "";
$output_array = array();
while ($reply_assoc = mysqli_fetch_assoc($reply_data)) {
    $reply_comment_id = $reply_assoc['comment_id'];
    $reply_board_id = $reply_assoc['board_id'];
    $reply_user_id = $reply_assoc['user_id'];
    $reply_text = $reply_assoc['reply'];
    $reply_timestamp = $reply_assoc['reply_timestamp'];

    $reply_user_data = find_user_data_by_id($reply_user_id);


    $profile_image = $reply_user_data['profile_picture']; 
    $profile_image_thumb = "../uploaded_pictures/profile/$reply_user_id/" . $reply_user_id . "small.png";

    if ($profile_image == "") {
        if ($comment_user_data['gender'] == "Male"){
            $user_profile_picture = "../images/ProfilePicMale.png";
        } else {
            $user_profile_picture = "../images/ProfilePicFemale.png";
        }
    } else {
        $user_profile_picture = $profile_image_thumb;
    }

    $full_name = ucfirst(htmlentities($reply_user_data['first_name'])) . " " . ucfirst(htmlentities($reply_user_data['last_name']));
    $time_of_post = time_of_post($reply_timestamp);
    $the_reply_text = nl2br($reply_text);

    $output = "<div class=\"reply_comment_div\">";
    $output .= "<a href=\"profile.php?user_id=$reply_user_id\" class=\"board_comments_div_picture\">";
    $output .= "<img src=\"$user_profile_picture\" width=\"50px\" height=\"50px\" /></a>";
    $output .= "<a href=\"profile.php?user_id=$reply_user_id\" class=\"board_comments_reply_link\">$full_name</a>";
    if ($reply_user_id == $_SESSION['user_id']){ 
        $output .= "<a href=\"edit_comment_board.php?comment_id=$reply_comment_id\" class=\"edit_comment_button_board\">Edit</a>";
        $output .= "<a href=\"widgets/delete_board_comment.php?board_id=$reply_board_id&comment_id=$reply_comment_id\" onclick=\"return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this admin?')\" class=\"delete_button_status\">Delete</a>";
    }
    $output .= "<div class=\"board_comment_submited_on\">submitted $time_of_post</div>";
    $output .= "<span class=\"comment_content_span\">$the_reply_text</span>";
    $output .= "</div>";

    $output_array[] = $output;
}
foreach ($output_array as $array) {
    echo $array;
}
}
```

?>

Comment: Start by inspecting the actual request in browser dev tools network. See what the response body actually looks like there. Also make sure url is correct there

Comment: you are using POST method in Ajax but GET in php file

Comment: correct it `if (isset($_GET["comment_id"])) { 
$comment_id = (int)$_GET["comment_id"];`

Comment: I inspected it that is why i knew it is giving an empty data
@Rahul i tried both but nothing :/

Answer (score 1):

try to store you data that is being sent to php page in data object

> **example:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    load_replies();
    function load_replies() {
    var commment_id = "<?php echo $board_comment_id_number;?>";
    $.ajax({
        url: "widgets/board_reply_fetch.php",
        data:{commentId:commment_id },//commment_id store it here
        method: "GET",
        success: function(data){
            $("#reply_comment").html(data);
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
  }
</script>
```

Comment: But now have POST/GET mismatch

Comment: relpace the POST with GET because in your php page you are using get method .

Comment: Should explain that in the answer

Comment: but can I do this when I dont have any forms ?

i added the data line in ajax and changed the php file to $_POST but now i dont get anything when i test the php file alone

Comment: @Nevil Saul Blemuss I changed it before and it did not work either :/

Comment: Please help ! this is so frustrating !

Answer (score 0):

Use POST METHOD:

```
if (isset($_POST["comment_id"])) { 
$comment_id = (int)$_POST["comment_id"];
```

Comment: Won't be set if OP doesn't change the ajax request since they are using url GET param

Comment: what changes? @charlietfl

Comment: oh yeah, there is no data

Comment: Exactly. You can have $_GET params on a POST though and although OP doesn't appear to need  POST they should still be able to access $_GET["comment_id"])`

Comment: yes yes, why don't you post a appropriate answer ! @charlietfl

Comment: Because what OP shows should work. Not enough known yet to troubleshoot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170424/discussion-between-rahul-and-charlietfl).

Comment: @charlietfl  tell me please what else should I post to troubleshoot ?

Comment: @firashelou did you do a deep inspection of the actual request in browser dev tools network? Can see what is sent, what is received, status, headers etc

Comment: @firashelou hit ctrl+shift+i if using chrome and go to network tab and XHR tab in same, check for request header

Comment: yes i printed in the console the back data it is giving "" i tried to send some static values from the php file and it worked well for example i send echo "11" or else and it echoes well but when i echo the array i want it is giving blank